# Скриншот экрана с ярлыками

Tags: delphi, windows, delphi-7, windows-10, screenshots

Вот код, который делает скриншот экрана. Он делает скриншот, но без ярлыков (просто фоновую картинку).

```
var bmp: TBitmap;
begin 
bmp := TBitmap.Create;
bmp.Width := Screen.Width;
bmp.Height := Screen.Height;
BitBlt(bmp.Canvas.Handle, 0,0, Screen.Width, Screen.Height,
       GetDC(FindWindow('ProgMan', nil)), 0,0,SRCCOPY);
Img1.Width := Screen.Width;
Img1.Height := Screen.Height;
Img1.Picture.Assign(bmp);
bmp.Free;
end;
```

Возможно ли сделать скриншот экрана с ярлыками? А еще лучше, со всеми открытыми окнами.

Comment: что за ОС? 

Comment: .OC Windows 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался. Надо поменять всего одну строчку и он будет делать скриншот экрана со всеми открытыми окнами:

```
BitBlt(bmp.Canvas.Handle, 0,0, Screen.Width, Screen.Height,
       GetDC(0), 0,0,SRCCOPY);
```